# SQL Query from two tables with repeating values in one of the tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

A little background. I'm building a auctioneer project (PHP/MySQL) where there is an unknown amount of images to be uploaded. The amount of images to be uploaded is to be defined by the user depending on amount of photos available. Uploading them online is no problem. I can see all the important info in the tables.

I have two relevant tables:

1. Properties (Mish/Mash of columns)
2. Images (Three columns: images_id, images_url, images_entry_id)

The images_entry_id refers to the unique properties.property_id. The problem lies in
when I upload several images; There is an unique id, url and they have the same images_entry_id so I can reference them to the Properties table. So when I try an inner join I get several of the same outputs from the properties table depending on the amount of images. Hope this explains what I mean?

My Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM properties INNER JOIN images
                ON properties.prop_id=images.images_entry_id ORDER BY properties.prop_id DESC";
```

So basically, if there are three images for one prop_id, I then get three outputs of the same output from the properties table! There! Any ideas? Is the database layout poor or is it just a simple query that has stared me in the face?

Comment: What do you want to get out of your query then?

Comment: I would like to output one instance from the properties table while outputting any related images from the images table. The link is the unique prop_id in the properties table and the images_entry_id in the images table.

Comment: Then you're probably better off doing it as two separate queries. If I'm not understanding you, can you post some sample data and output?

Comment: Thanks, how could I query both separately and have yet the output together?

Answer (score 0):

ok, this will work:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT properties.* FROM properties 
INNER JOIN images ON (properties.prop_id=images.images_entry_id) 
ORDER BY properties.prop_id DESC";
```

or this one

```
$sql = "SELECT properties.* FROM properties 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM images WHERE properties.prop_id=images.images_entry_id) 
ORDER BY properties.prop_id DESC";
```

Comment: The group by suggestion limits it to one property output but I can only output one image with each query? If I stick in a foreach loop like this: foreach ($q as $result) {echo "<img src='uploads/Properties/".$result->images_url."' />";} I only get the one image whereas there is multiple images.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I am getting this error with both codes above: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$images_url in...

Comment: nothing to do with the query. it's related to your code. search and find where is $images_url

Answer (score 0):

Your expected results would not come from a single query of joined tables, you would need to query each table independently.

Comment: I think it will have to be two separate queries. Is there a particular way I can co-ordinate the two queries into one output? Thanks.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, at least not directly. You could add an intermediary step that would combine them in PHP, but 2 queries would still need to be ran and returned to php separately to do that.